# Extracting information from XML using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

XML below is shaped in an unusual way. How would I extract all the pairs of field names and field values from following XML using XQuery in SQL Server? I am particular interested in extracting field values with a field name of `1006`.

```
<details>
  <fieldname>1006</fieldname>
  <fieldvalue>HSBC BANK PLC</fieldvalue>
</details>
<details>
  <fieldname>1005</fieldname>
  <fieldvalue>POOLE   LONGFLEET</fieldvalue>
</details>
<details>
  <fieldname>1059</fieldname>
  <fieldvalue>165-167 High Street</fieldvalue>
</details>
<details>
  <fieldname>1063</fieldname>
  <fieldvalue>POOLE</fieldvalue>
</details>
```

I have a relatively large number of XMLs to process and so far I have been using a combination of `patIndex` and `substring` to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one-

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = '
<details>
  <fieldname>1006</fieldname>
  <fieldvalue>HSBC BANK PLC</fieldvalue>
</details>
<details>
  <fieldname>1006</fieldname>
  <fieldvalue>test2</fieldvalue>
</details>
<details>
  <fieldname>1005</fieldname>
  <fieldvalue>POOLE   LONGFLEET</fieldvalue>
</details>
<details>
  <fieldname>1059</fieldname>
  <fieldvalue>165-167 High Street</fieldvalue>
</details>
<details>
  <fieldname>1063</fieldname>
  <fieldvalue>POOLE</fieldvalue>
</details>'

SELECT 
      fieldname = t.c.value('./fieldname[1]', 'INT')
    , fieldvalue = t.c.value('./fieldvalue[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM @XML.nodes('details') t(c)
WHERE t.c.value('./fieldname[1]', 'INT') = 1006
```

In output -

[image: tt]

**Update:**

In example, `XML` don't have a `ROOT` node, so you just need correctly specify the path:

```
SELECT t.c.query('.')
FROM @XML.nodes('details') t(c)
```

Query split your nodes into rows:

[image: tt]

After it, for each row you can get the data via `XML` method `value`:

```
t.c.value('<path>', '<datatype>')
```

For additional information read this [topic](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2889/basic-sql-server-xml-querying/).

Comment: Great this works! Could you give me a brief explanation how it works?

Comment: You're welcome @wujtehacjusz and also, please, see the update.